# vPC over Dark Fiber

Tags: vpc, cisco-nexus

Recently, I was asked to implement ***vPC*** connections over ***Dark Fiber*** between two data centers. Is this possible, and, if it is possible, does it have any drawbacks or limitations? I'm asked to encrypt the data involved in the ***vPC*** using ***MACsec***. I know it is a very hard task, but any help would be useful.

Comment: Which sort of VPC do you mean (Virtual Private Cloud, Virtual Port Channel, or something else)?

Comment: Virtual Port Channel

Comment: This sounds like a case of management reading a term and saying "implement that!".  While I'm sure VPC over two data centers is technically possible, I don't think there's a reason you should.  You may want to look at some sort of a data center interconnect protocol, or get the reasons and scope of what management wants out of connecting both data centers.

Comment: i just do what i asked for as you know customer allwes right think godness it wasn't OTV

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Three words:  Don't do it.

There are many reasons why, but the most important is that instead of making  resilient links, you have made both data centers vulnerable to the same problem.  If the VPC link goes down, both data centers will think they're active.  That almost certainly means that nothing will work until you restore the link.  Not exactly a robust system is it?

Comment: may i can cofigure vpc autorecovery

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you can make it work.   I just predict a day will come when you wish you hadn't.

Comment: Also too, depending on the length of your dark fiber, and if you're using DWDM - you would almost definitely (eventually) see your VPC go split brained, without seeing any of the physical links flap.  Microflaps can break networks.  AND if it's provided via a third party and you're leasing it (Zayo, Level3, whoever) you're at their mercy for maintenance.  They will perform maintenance whenever they want, very rarely will you or your company pushing back do anything, you'll also be lucky if they tell you.

Comment: Why not suggest making it redundant instead of just saying it's all out a bad idea?

Comment: @kll Because it is a bad idea.  You are just complicating a bad design.  There are other ways to achieve redundancy that don't have such catastrophic failure modes.

Comment: @RonTrunk I really think that deserves a lengthier explanation. It's as if your emphasis on three words alone should make all of us trust your word that it's a bad idea. Given it's dark fibre we are talking about and not DWDM, the implied distance is ~metro area. I don't see why doing redundant vPC over such distances would be worse than doing it within a single large DC.

Comment: @kll I don't mean to argue from authority, but I have built stretched L2 networks before, and I have seen them fail due to "reliable" links going down.  As I said, it will work, and maybe you'll be lucky and nothing will happen.  But when I design networks, I avoid stretched L2 links whenever I can.  Just because a technology exists, doesn't mean you have to put it everywhere.   When you're trying to make data centers reliable, you don't want a failure to affect both sites -- that's the opposite of what you're trying to achieve.  And that's the problem with using VPCs in this case.

Comment: @RonTrunk I agree completely. I loathe large L2. Would be nice if you put something along those lines in your answer. One could argue over failure domains here, it is not entirely clear that the two data centres are for redundancy or if there are two simple because there wasn't enough space in the first one.

Comment: @kll  Fair enough.